# Why is my laptop is typing z continuously?

Tags: keyboard

Even after rebooting, my laptop prints z over and over. I cleaned the keyboard and checked if the z was pressed down, it it not.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

The key migh've broke.
You can delete the keyboard's driver at Device Manager and see if the problem persists ( the driver will self-install automatically at reboot, so don't hesitate.. you also can download it from the manufacturer's website if that's a concern in any way )

- If so, then it's a software that doing this ( might be AHK but could be something malicious, since that not usually happens ).
- If the problem will stop without the driver, then you need to replace the laptops' keyboard.

Also, try to disconnect any physical device from the laptop and see if the problem persists.

Comment: Wow! Thank you!  That worked! It seems so easy now. I was afraid to delete the keyboard, but I followed your instructions. Thank you so much!! I certainly appreciate your help!

Comment: @Margo Awesome! May I ask what was the problem? FYI - You can also disconnect the keyboard physically, inside the laptop, so it won't reappear on the next boot. It should be a small flat cable... I recommend watching a guide relevant to your laptop, if that's what you'll choose to do.

Comment: @Margo Welcome to the community. If an answer proves helpful, you should [accept](https://superuser.com/help/accepted-answer) it. SE sites aren't discussion boards, I'd recommend taking the quick [Tour](https://superuser.com/tour) and checking the [Help](https://superuser.com/help) to learn how the sites work.